# Calculating coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have a generating function,
$$ \frac{(1-x^7)^6}{(1-x)^6} $$
and I want to calculate the coefficient of $x^{26}$

Solution for this is,

$$ {26+5 \choose 5} - 6{19+5 \choose 5} + 15{12+5 \choose 5} - 20{5+5 \choose 5} $$

Is there formula for this? If there is, what is called?
If there is no formula, how can I calculate it?

Thanks!

Comment: the coefficient is given by $$2667$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner my question is how come $$ \frac{(1-x^7)^6}{(1-x)^6} $$  this generating function be $$ {26+5 \choose 5} - 6{19+5 \choose 5} + 15{12+5 \choose 5} - 20{5+5 \choose 5} $$, not just it value

Comment: You should be able to use the fact that, by the geometric sum formula, $$ \frac{1-x^7}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^6 x^k, $$ and then apply the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{26}]}&\color{blue}{\frac{\left(1-x^7\right)^6}{\left(1-x\right)^6}}\\
> &=[x^{26}]\left(1-x^7\right)^6\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-6}{j}(-x)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{26}]\left(1-\binom{6}{1}x^7+\binom{6}{2}x^{14}-\binom{6}{3}x^{21}\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+5}{5}x^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{26}]-6[x^{19}]+15[x^{12}]-20[x^5]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+5}{5}x^j\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{31}{5}-6\binom{24}{5}+15\binom{17}{5}-20\binom{10}{5}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we expand the denominator using the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (2) we expand the polynomial up to powers of $x^{21}$ since higher powers do not contribute to $[x^{26}]$ and we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (4) we select the coefficients accordingly.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Negative binomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html):

$$\begin{align}[x^{26}]\frac{(1-x^7)^6}{(1-x)^6}&=[x^{26}](1-x^7)^6\cdot (1-x)^{-6}=\\
&=[x^{26}]\sum_{i=0}^6 {6\choose i}(-x^7)^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {-6\choose j}(-x)^j=\\
&=[x^{26}]\sum_{i=0}^6 {6\choose i}(-x^7)^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} {6+j-1\choose j}x^j=\\
&=[x^{26}]\left[{6\choose 0}(-x^7)^0\cdot {6+26-1\choose 26}x^{26}+\\
\qquad \qquad {6\choose 1}(-x^7)^1\cdot {6+19-1\choose 19}x^{19}+\\
\qquad \qquad {6\choose 2}(-x^7)^2\cdot {6+12-1\choose 12}x^{12}+\\
\qquad \qquad {6\choose 3}(-x^7)^3\cdot {6+5-1\choose 5}x^{5}+\right]=\\
&={6\choose 0}{31\choose 26}-{6\choose 1}{24\choose 19}+{6\choose 2}{17\choose 12}-{6\choose 3}{10\choose 5}.\end{align}$$

Comment: This is the same answer which I've already provided some hours before.

Comment: @Markus Scheuer, I should note that you answer is excellent with the detailed steps and the references. However, I would not call our answers the same, I think there are several differences. For example, you are referring to the formula for $(1+x)^{\alpha}$, while I to $(x+a)^{-n}$; you expanded the 1st binomial 1st and then the 2nd, while I did it at once (since it is a multiplication). And my answer is no way undermining yours, but only supporting. Peace and respect to all.